# Как поделить произведение чисел на все повторяющиеся множители, чтобы осталось наименьшее общее кратное?

Tags: python, логические-выражения

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
n = 2
multi = x * y
while ((x // n != 1) and (x % n != 0)) or ((y // n != 1) and (y % n != 0)):
    if x % n == 0 and y % n == 0:
        multi = multi // n
    n += 1
print(multi)
```

Хочу поделить произведение чисел на все повторяющиеся множители, чтобы осталось наименьшее общее кратное. Но не могу пройти дальше n = 3  :(
При n = 3 выходит из цикла и я не понимаю почему.

Answer (score 1):

Операция "И" истинна, только если оба истинны. У вас получается по одному ложному условию в каждой скобке.

Вот пример решения вашей задачи

```
def gcd(a,b):
    """Наибольший общий делитель"""
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Наименьшее общее кратное"""
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)
```

И вызов

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
print(lcm(x,y))
```